# Runs se dividindo várias vezes

Tags: c#, microsoft-word, office-open-xml

Bom galera, estou tendo um problema que está me perturbando um pouco, já procurei sobre e não achei nada que me ajudasse.

Estou pesquisando certas variáveis num **Template Word** para poder realizar uma substituição. O problema ocorre quando algumas variáveis são quebradas em várias **Runs**, por exemplo:

[image: Image do debug]

NT: Nessa imagem fica claro que a variável **municipio_sigla** é quebrada em duas **Runs**, sendo a **Run1 => munici**, e a **Run2 => pio_sigla**, portando ao procurar ela completa (**municipio_sigla**) não retornará resultado algum.

**Edit1:** Aqui vai um exemplo do código:

```
//Pegando os cabeçalhos
SearchAndReplace(partLists: document.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts, target: "<municipio_sigla>", replace: municipio.Sigla);

//Método que procura e substitui as variáveis:
private static void SearchAndReplace<T>(IEnumerable<T> partLists, string target, string replace) where T : OpenXmlPart
{
        foreach (var part in partLists)
        {
            foreach (var currentParagraph in part.RootElement.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph>())
            {
                foreach (var currentRun in currentParagraph.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run>())
                {
                    foreach (var currentText in currentRun.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>())
                    {
                        if (currentText.Text.Contains(target))
                        {
                            currentText.Text = currentText.Text.ReplaceInsensitive(target, replace);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Alguém já enfretou algo parecido? E se sim, existe alguma solução?

Comment: Será mais fácil de ajudar se você editar a pergunta, incluindo o seu código.

Comment: Pois é kkkkkkk. Um momento.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, pronto. Adicionei um código de exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom galera, eu consegui encontrar uma resposta muito interessante no [stackoverflow gringo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34709986/6000539) em que dizia que variáveis desse tipo podem trazer problema, pois o OpenXml separa textos assim, que tenham algum caractere especial (<,>,@,#,$...). Essa resposta me levou a esse [código do Simon Doodkin](https://gist.github.com/shimondoodkin/7471075).

Ele pega os textos das Runs e concatena em uma string, procura o valor a ser substituído e substitui pelas as posições de cada caractere.

Acabei fazendo um código pra me facilitar na hora de fazer as substituições, e ele se encontra [aqui](https://gist.github.com/marciocristian/33798ef5a077b264127532ba28c917a1), pra quem tiver interesse...

Exemplo de uso:

```
wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.ReplaceInElement("from", "to");
```